# Can't access my PC using external IP

Tags: nat, ip, network-access

I am currently in a setup where I connect to the internet using wired internet. I directly plug in an ethernet wire from the ISP. They have provided me an internal LAN IP address which in turn is mapped to a static external IP address using NAT. The setup is like this:

**Laptop -> Ethernet Port(Internal IP) -> ISP Gateway -> External IP**

I want to access services such as WAMP, RDP, VNC on my Win 10 laptop from the internet but am unable to do so using the external IP. But I am able to access everything when I am using the internal IP of my network. I did a traceroute of connections both to and fro from my machine. The results are as follows:

```
Tracing route to google.com [216.58.196.110] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  172.16.161.129   
  2     *        1 ms     1 ms  node-103-249-5-97.alliancebroadband.in [103.249.5.97]   
  3     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  aes-static-017.50.144.59.airtel.in [59.144.50.17]   
  4    36 ms    35 ms    35 ms  182.79.243.18   
  5    35 ms    36 ms    35 ms  72.14.242.178   
  6    36 ms    37 ms    35 ms  216.239.56.32   
  7    36 ms    36 ms    35 ms  216.239.40.45   
  8    36 ms    36 ms    36 ms  maa03s19-in-f110.1e100.net [216.58.196.110]

Trace complete.
```

Reverse trace:

```
traceroute to 45.249.69.90 (45.249.69.90), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets


1               *   *   *               
2   core22.hetzner.de   213.239.229.133 de  0.238 ms    0.260 ms     
    core21.hetzner.de   213.239.229.129 de  0.212 ms                
3   core4.hetzner.de    213.239.245.14  de  4.857 ms         
    core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.218 de  4.863 ms     
    core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.177 de  4.861 ms    
4   dx1.in.airtel.com   80.81.194.250   de  20.908 ms   20.913 ms   20.912 ms               
5               *   *   *           
6   aes-static-018.50.144.59.airtel.in  59.144.50.18    in  160.893 ms  159.746 ms  161.467 ms              
7   node-103-249-5-133.alliancebroadband.in 103.249.5.133   in  159.026 ms  159.177 ms  159.407 ms
8               *   *   *
9               *   *   *
10              *   *   *
No reply for 3 hops. Assuming we reached firewall.
```

I am confused by the fact that the last node of my ISP is different for both cases. **103.249.5.97** for outgoing and **103.249.5.133** for incoming. Is that normal?

Also, 3rd party remote desktop services such as **teamviewer** or **webex** are working fine. How does this work then?

Any help how I get this to work will be much appreciated.

**Note:** Windows Firewall is disabled at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hop, `172.16.161.129`, belongs to your ISP (based on what you have written), and that is an RFC 1918 private IPv4 address. That means your ISP is using CGN. You need to forward the specific ports on the NAT, but the NAT belongs to the ISP, so you can't do that, and the ISP will not do it for you since those ports would only work for you, and none of the other customers using that IPv4 address.

As far as having different addresses, asymmetric routing is common. Traffic can come back a different way than it went out.

Since this is your business, you need to pay your ISP for a public, usually static, IPv4 address if you want to be able to get to your network from the public Internet.

Comment: Thanks Ron for your reply. I was also assuming so.172.16.161.129 is the IP of the gateway of my segment. But how does services like teamviewer and webex make it work then?

Comment: The same way it does if the NAT was on your router: NAT builds a table when you initiate a connection, and return traffic can come back in. Seriously, if you want to run a business, you need to get your own public IP address.

Comment: You are correct Ron. So marking your answer as accepted. But I do not require it for business Ron. It is actually for personal purpose. I had a chat with my ISP & the cost they are asking is way too much for my needs. I heard that RDP/VNC can be done over reverse SSH. Don't know whether it can be done in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, home networking is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: +1 with one minor remark for completeness: the 2 different ip's don't necessarily mean there is asymmetric routing, they could be 2 addresses of the same router. It would actually be strange to see the same address in an inbound and outbound traceroute since the router responds with the ip address of the interface towards the source.

Comment: @hertitu, assuming they are different networks, then yes, they could be different interfaces on the same router. They may be in the same network,  and couldn't be on the same router in that case.